# Should I build individual apps or build one with a coded log in?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, content-management-system, backend

I’m building apps for multiple Home Owners Associations (HOAs). Each app is branded with their community logo, etc., and would have a short property code to log-in.

At first, the thought was to build individual apps for each property. Now, I’m wondering if it’d be better and more efficient to have a single “portal” app that initially asks for their specific property-code.

After code entry it would bring them to their property’s dashboard.

What would I generally need set up on the back end to build that?

Is it better than creating individual apps for each property?

Any informed opinions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should submit a single app that allows the user to select their property. Submitting multiple, essentially identical, apps will lead to rejection during review.

This is covered by clause 4.3 of the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#design)

> **4.3 Spam**
>
> Don’t create multiple Bundle IDs of the same app. If your app has different versions for specific locations, sports teams, universities, etc., consider submitting a single app and provide the variations using in-app purchase.

Note that using in-app purchase is just an example. It is not required and would not apply in the situation you describe.

Unfortunately, your other question regarding a back end is too broad for this site and is asking for recommendations. These are off-topic.